# How do you format Facebook Wall posts?

Tags: facebook, formatting

There doesn't appear to be any formatting links when I do a Facebook Wall post.  Is there any way to do formatting like HTML, markup, etc?

Comment: I've also wondered about that, and specifically whether you can create a clean "inline" [link](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/8456/2303) in FB posts (I already know you can link to other profiles using "@")...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You used to be able to add formatting to posts by creating a Note type post, but Facebook have now removed that functionality, so read on for other options.

If you want to be able to use formatting in a normal status update or a comment on someone's timeline you can use a tool that converts your text into different unicode fonts, depending on which formatting type you require, which you can copy and paste into the status or comment box.

Here's a list of font changing tools you can use :

http://fsymbols.com/generators/

https://mothereff.in/twitalics

http://www.gschoppe.com/projects/fbformat/

http://slothsoft.net/UnicodeMapper/

http://qaz.wtf/u/convert.cgi

**UPDATE July 2019** Facebook now lets you add limited formatting to "Group" posts.
[image: Screenshot shows formatting options for Group posts]

If you click the back to front **P** type character in the update box, as shown in the screenshot, a few formatting options are displayed, "**H1**", "**H2**", Unordered List, Numbered List, Quotation. Also if you select any of the text you have written in the group post box, two more formatting options will pop up above the text, "**Bold**" and "**Italic**". These options are not available for comments on group posts, just the posts themselves.

Comment: Care to provide an example or a screenshot to 'prove' the concept?

Comment: I'm not sure if there's an official published list of the tags that work anywhere. I do know that I've used <b>, <i>, <a>, and <img> there before.

Comment: While I don't understand what the purpose of Facebook Notes are, this definitely has turned out to be the solution.

Comment: the purpose of facebook notes, along with the rest of facebooks functions is for the users to generate free content which facebook can add adverts alongside, to generate revenue.

Comment: @TomG: new link: https://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=105279816229046

Comment: To clarify: create a note INSTEAD of a status update - the note will appear on your wall, too. To create a note, go to your profile (click on your name at the top), click on the `More` dropdown menu, then select `Notes`. Note, however, that since you cannot _respond_ with a note, you won't be able to use markup in a _comment on_ another wall post.

Comment: Facebook have now removed the notes feature, so im gonna update the answer to explain you cant use them anymore.

Answer (score 6):

This site offers one solution: by replacing the characters themselves with unicode equivalents, you can format text anywhere.

> ♥
>
> This is some example text showing all the different formatting options offered.
>
> e̶x̶a̶m̶p̶l̶e̶ ℯ    d̶i̶f̶f̶e̶r̶e̶n̶t̶ ℴℊ  .

However, if your users don't have a font installed that has the various characters available, they might see little boxes or question marks instead.

http://www.gschoppe.com/projects/fbformat/

Comment: Can you offer a bit of information as to why this is a good solution, as, if the link goes dead, the answer will not be worth anything.

Comment: Note, that their formatting doesn't show up in mobile devices.  It makes the letters look like little squares.

Comment: it doesn't show on devices without appropriate fonts, regardless of mobile or PC. So if you install the needed fonts on the phone it'll work. PCs without that font won't show them

Answer (score -1):

I think the only way to do this is by using a 3rd Party Application.

1. go to [Profile HTML](http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=6165549526) Facebook application page
2. click on `Go to application` and then on `Allow`
3. insert your HTML code inside the “your code” text area
4. click on `submit` to save your HTML code
5. click on `add to profile`, select `wall and info tab` and choose `add`

[Source Article](http://mycomputermadesimple.blogspot.com/2009/03/html-in-facebook-wall.html)

Comment: I did all that, got it all perfect, but then I could never get the tab to show on my profile.  When I click on `add to profile` I get a box with no pages/tabs in it.  His help-contact link just takes me back to my own profile page.

Comment: Found out why: __Facebook has been giving out notices that 3rd-party applications will not be allowed on the tabs / boxes ---- Profile HTML cannot be used on Facebook anymore.__

Comment: Ah I see - well it seems that it is not possible to do then. Sorry!