# How do you post a Facebook Note in a group or on a page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, facebook-groups

To make [formatted posts on Facebook](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/8456/how-do-you-format-facebook-wall-posts) you have to use [Notes](https://www.facebook.com/help/488014787881885).  This is fine for posting on your wall, but how do I post a Note to a group or page, or is it impossible to post a formatted post using those Facebook venues?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your notes on a Page you can go to Notes. When you get there click create. Write what you wish to. you can also Copy And Paste in the Note you are making. This also works the same way on a Group Page only you will click on files at the top of the page instead of Notes.

Answer (score 1):

Use a graphics programme (MS Paint etc) to make an image file, and post that instead.

Comment: That's one alternative I've been told about, it's just unhandy for large posts.

Answer (score 1):

In your group head to 'Files' (next to photos) and then upload or create a doc -> This is the equivalent of notes for groups. Huge character limit so you shouldn't run out either.